# Can multiple columns of a Pandas DataFrame be sliced by different values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date time indexed DataFrame, (65 columns (only 9 shown for clarity) -> number of sensors, and x rows -> number of observations(for the sample data I limited it to 700 rows, to illustrate the issue I am having).
demo csv: 
https://pastebin.com/mpSgJF94

```
    swp_data = pd.read_csv(FILE_NAME, index_col=0, header=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
swp_data = swp_data.sort_index()
```

For each column, I need to find the point where the value is 95% of the column max value, and figure out from the beginning of the DataFrame to the 95% point, where the difference between the time steps is greater than a given value (0.2 in this case).

something similar to what would work in R (not actual code but an illustration)

```
  for (i in 1 : 95% point){
  difference[i] <- s[i] - s[(i-1)]
}
breaking <-which(difference > 0.2)[1]
```

Which would take the 95% point as the end index of a loop, and look at the differences between the time steps and return an index value where the difference > 0.2

In pandas I have calculated the following:
95% value

```
    s95 = (swp_data.max() + (swp_data.max() * .05))
```

A1-24,   -20.6260635,
A1-18,   -17.863923,
A1-12,   -11.605629,
A2-24,   -16.755144,
A2-18,   -17.6815275,
A2-12,   -16.369584,
A3-24,   -15.5030295,

95% time

```
    s95_time = (swp_data >= (swp_data.max() + (swp_data.max() * .05))).idxmax()
```

A1-24,   10/2/2011 1:30,
A1-18,   10/3/2011 6:20,
A1-12,   10/2/2011 17:20,
A2-24,   10/3/2011 6:10,
A2-18,   10/3/2011 1:30,
A2-12,  10/2/2011 17:10,
A3-24,   10/2/2011 1:30,

Thus far, I have the max value, and the 95% value, as well as a series of timestamps where each column reached its 95% point. 
s95 value:

I have tried to mask the DataFrame, (trying to replicate R's which) by creating a boolean DataFrame of values <= 95% point, and have tried df.where using values >=95%. Neither mask or where has provided me what I need, as some of the sensors can already be above the 95% of max when I started recording (mask returns NaN for these values), while where returns these values but not the values below the 95% threshold.

The output I am looking for would be something along the lines of

```
      A1-24, A1-18, A1-12, A2-24, A2-18, A2-12, A3-24, A3-18, A3-12
BREAKING  hh:mm, hh:mm, hh:mm, hh:mm, hh:mm, hh:mm, hh:mm, hh:mm, hh:mm
```

where hh:mm equals the time from the start of the data file to the breaking value.

So far what I have found on SE and google, has me confused if I can subset the columns of the dataframe by different values, and am having trouble figuring out what I am trying to do is called.

edit:  @Prateek Comment:

What i am trying to do is find a way that I can somewhat automate this process, so that using the position of 95% I can have the breaking point returned. I have ~200 csv files that I am trying to process, and would like as much of the filtering to be done using the 95% and breaking positions as possible.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you want to do but swp_data.diff() should give you difference between row and the value above it. Then you could filter out values > 0.2 and find first occurence before your threshold indexes

Comment: 1.) What do you mean exactly by `the point where the value is 95% of the column max value`?   2.) What is the period for the `0.2` difference threshold? Comparing values with previous timestamp `diff(periods=1)` give only one matching value.

Comment: 1.) I am looking for the index of the value in each column, where column.diff() >0.2.

2.)The period that I am looking at is from the first observation, to the observation that is equals (column.max() + (column.max() * 0.05)). The time from the start to the value described is variable for each column, and each csv file I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution from what I understand.
Note that I renamed `swap_data` to `df` in the example, and the solution is tested on the provided csv sample file from your question.

#### Find duration from the start up to when value reaches 95% of column's max

Finding the first timepoint where each column reaches 95% of the max is done as you described:

```
idx = (df >= df.max(axis=0) * 1.05).idxmax()

>>> idx
Out[]:
A1-24   2011-10-02 01:30:00
A1-18   2011-10-03 06:20:00
A1-12   2011-10-02 17:20:00
A2-24   2011-10-03 06:10:00
A2-18   2011-10-03 01:30:00
A2-12   2011-10-02 17:10:00
A3-24   2011-10-02 01:30:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note the using `df.max() * 1.05` avoids to compute the `max` twice, as compared to `s95 = (swp_data.max() + (swp_data.max() * .05))` otherwise it's the same.

Then computing the duration from the start of the dataframe is obtained by substracting the first timestamp

```
>>> idx - df.index[0]
Out[]:
A1-24   0 days 00:00:00
A1-18   1 days 04:50:00
A1-12   0 days 15:50:00
A2-24   1 days 04:40:00
A2-18   1 days 00:00:00
A2-12   0 days 15:40:00
A3-24   0 days 00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

This is for each column the time spent from the start of the record to the `s95` point.
Time is 0 if the first recorded value is already above this point.

#### Mask the dataframe to cover this period

```
mask = pd.concat([pd.Series(df.index)] * df.columns.size, axis=1) < idx.values.T
df_masked = df.where(mask.values)

>>> df_masked.dropna(how='all')
Out[]:
                     A1-24     A1-18     A1-12     A2-24     A2-18     A2-12  A3-24
Timestamp
2011-10-02 01:30:00    NaN -18.63589 -16.90389 -17.26780 -19.20653 -19.59666    NaN
2011-10-02 01:40:00    NaN -18.64686 -16.93100 -17.26832 -19.22702 -19.62036    NaN
2011-10-02 01:50:00    NaN -18.65098 -16.92761 -17.26132 -19.22705 -19.61355    NaN
2011-10-02 02:00:00    NaN -18.64307 -16.94764 -17.27702 -19.22746 -19.63462    NaN
2011-10-02 02:10:00    NaN -18.66338 -16.94900 -17.27325 -19.25358 -19.62761    NaN
2011-10-02 02:20:00    NaN -18.66217 -16.95625 -17.27386 -19.25455 -19.64009    NaN
2011-10-02 02:30:00    NaN -18.66015 -16.96130 -17.27040 -19.25898 -19.64241    NaN
2011-10-02 02:40:00    NaN -18.66883 -16.96980 -17.27580 -19.27054 -19.65454    NaN
2011-10-02 02:50:00    NaN -18.68635 -16.97897 -17.27488 -19.28492 -19.65808    NaN
2011-10-02 03:00:00    NaN -18.68009 -16.99057 -17.28346 -19.28928 -19.67182    NaN
2011-10-02 03:10:00    NaN -18.68450 -17.00258 -17.28196 -19.32272 -19.68135    NaN
2011-10-02 03:20:00    NaN -18.68777 -17.01009 -17.29675 -19.30864 -19.68747    NaN
2011-10-02 03:30:00    NaN -18.70067 -17.01706 -17.29178 -19.32034 -19.69742    NaN
2011-10-02 03:40:00    NaN -18.70095 -17.03559 -17.29352 -19.32741 -19.70945    NaN
2011-10-02 03:50:00    NaN -18.70636 -17.03651 -17.28925 -19.33549 -19.71560    NaN
2011-10-02 04:00:00    NaN -18.70937 -17.03548 -17.28996 -19.33433 -19.71211    NaN
2011-10-02 04:10:00    NaN -18.70599 -17.04444 -17.29223 -19.33740 -19.72227    NaN
2011-10-02 04:20:00    NaN -18.71292 -17.05510 -17.29449 -19.35154 -19.72779    NaN
2011-10-02 04:30:00    NaN -18.72158 -17.06376 -17.28770 -19.35647 -19.73064    NaN
2011-10-02 04:40:00    NaN -18.72185 -17.06910 -17.30018 -19.36785 -19.74481    NaN
2011-10-02 04:50:00    NaN -18.72048 -17.06599 -17.29004 -19.37320 -19.73424    NaN
2011-10-02 05:00:00    NaN -18.73083 -17.07618 -17.29528 -19.37319 -19.75045    NaN
2011-10-02 05:10:00    NaN -18.72215 -17.08587 -17.29650 -19.38400 -19.75713    NaN
2011-10-02 05:20:00    NaN -18.73206 -17.10233 -17.29767 -19.39254 -19.76838    NaN
2011-10-02 05:30:00    NaN -18.73719 -17.09621 -17.29842 -19.39363 -19.76258    NaN
2011-10-02 05:40:00    NaN -18.73839 -17.10910 -17.29237 -19.40390 -19.76864    NaN
2011-10-02 05:50:00    NaN -18.74257 -17.12091 -17.29398 -19.40846 -19.78042    NaN
2011-10-02 06:00:00    NaN -18.74327 -17.12995 -17.29097 -19.41153 -19.77897    NaN
2011-10-02 06:10:00    NaN -18.74326 -17.04482 -17.28397 -19.40928 -19.77430    NaN
2011-10-02 06:20:00    NaN -18.73100 -16.86221 -17.28575 -19.40956 -19.78396    NaN
...                    ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...    ...
2011-10-03 01:20:00    NaN -18.16448       NaN -16.99797 -17.95030       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 01:30:00    NaN -18.15606       NaN -16.98879       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 01:40:00    NaN -18.12795       NaN -16.97951       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 01:50:00    NaN -18.12974       NaN -16.97937       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 02:00:00    NaN -18.11848       NaN -16.96770       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 02:10:00    NaN -18.11879       NaN -16.95256       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 02:20:00    NaN -18.08212       NaN -16.95461       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 02:30:00    NaN -18.09060       NaN -16.94141       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 02:40:00    NaN -18.07000       NaN -16.93006       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 02:50:00    NaN -18.07461       NaN -16.91700       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 03:00:00    NaN -18.06039       NaN -16.91466       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 03:10:00    NaN -18.04229       NaN -16.89537       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 03:20:00    NaN -18.03514       NaN -16.89753       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 03:30:00    NaN -18.03014       NaN -16.88813       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 03:40:00    NaN -18.00851       NaN -16.88086       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 03:50:00    NaN -18.01028       NaN -16.87721       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 04:00:00    NaN -18.00227       NaN -16.86687       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 04:10:00    NaN -17.98804       NaN -16.85424       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 04:20:00    NaN -17.96740       NaN -16.84466       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 04:30:00    NaN -17.96451       NaN -16.84205       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 04:40:00    NaN -17.95414       NaN -16.82609       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 04:50:00    NaN -17.93661       NaN -16.81903       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 05:00:00    NaN -17.92905       NaN -16.80737       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 05:10:00    NaN -17.92743       NaN -16.80582       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 05:20:00    NaN -17.91504       NaN -16.78991       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 05:30:00    NaN -17.89965       NaN -16.78469       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 05:40:00    NaN -17.89945       NaN -16.77288       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 05:50:00    NaN -17.88822       NaN -16.76610       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 06:00:00    NaN -17.87259       NaN -16.75742       NaN       NaN    NaN
2011-10-03 06:10:00    NaN -17.87308       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN

[173 rows x 7 columns]
```

To achieve this you have to compute a `bool` mask for each column:

1. create a dataframe with the `DateTimeIndex` values repeated over the same number of columns as `df`: `pd.concat([pd.Series(df.index)] * df.columns.size, axis=1)`.
   Here `df.index` must be turned into a `pd.Series` for concatenation, then repeated to match the number of columns `df.columns.size`.
2. create the mask itself with `< idx.values.T`, where `values` gets `idx` as a `numpy.array` and `T` transposes it in order to compare column-wise with the dataframe.
3. mask the dataframe with `df.where(mask.values)`, where using `values` gets the mask as a `numpy.array`. This is needed as the mask does not have the same labels as `df`.
4. optionally only keep the rows where a least one value is not `NaN` using `.dropna(how='all')`

#### Filter masked data on the difference between each time point

If I understand well it is the point where you want to filter your data on `difference > 0.2` between each time point and for the selected period only.
It remains a bit unclear to me so do not hesitate to discuss in the comments if I misunderstood.

This can be done with:

```
df[df_masked.diff(1) > 0.2]
```

But unfortunately for the provided dataset there is no value matching these conditions.

```
>>> df[df_masked.diff(1) > 0.2].any()
Out[]:
A1-24    False
A1-18    False
A1-12    False
A2-24    False
A2-18    False
A2-12    False
A3-24    False
dtype: bool
```

---

**Edit: vizualize results as `bool` dataframe** (comments follow-up)

Visualizing the results as a boolean dataframe with index and columns is done very simply with `df_masked.diff(1) > 0.2`.
However there will likely be a lot of unnecessary rows containing only `False`, so you can filter it this way:

```
df_diff = df_masked.diff(1) > 0.1  # Raising the threshold a bit to get some values

>>> df_diff[df_diff.any(axis=1)]
Out[]:
                     A1-24  A1-18  A1-12  A2-24  A2-18  A2-12  A3-24
Timestamp
2011-10-02 06:20:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 06:30:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 06:40:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 06:50:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 07:00:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 07:10:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 07:20:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 07:30:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 07:40:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 07:50:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 08:00:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 08:10:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 08:20:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 08:30:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 08:40:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 08:50:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 09:00:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 09:10:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 09:20:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 09:30:00  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2011-10-02 12:20:00  False  False  False  False  False   True  False
2011-10-02 12:50:00  False  False  False  False   True   True  False
2011-10-02 13:10:00  False  False  False  False  False   True  False
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you @FabienP, for the sample I provided I do not think there was a response at the .2 threshold, but for the rest of the files I have there might be. 
To get the datetime out of the last boolean mask:

       df[df_masked.diff(1) > 0.2]

I can just do:

       df[df_masked.diff(1) > 0.2].idxmax()
Correct?

Comment: @zapmaster321, no, `idxmax()` will only return the index of the first occurrence of the maximum. What is the format you're looking for? `df[(df_masked.diff(1) > 0.2)].dropna(how='all')` will give you the filtered dataframe of all values matching the condition. And `df[(df_masked.diff(1) > 0.2)]["A1-12"].dropna(how='all').index` will give you the indexes for the specific column "A1-12".

Comment: the format I am looking for is a series (or dataframe) that has the sensor name and the datetime of the condition`df[(df_masked.diff(1) > 0.2)].dropna(how='all') ` being true.

Comment: Then it's simply `(df_masked.diff(1) > 0.2)` that you can use with masking to remove unnecessary rows containing only `False`. Just to see how it will look like you can use a lower threshold for the difference (0.08 should give you several values on the test dataset). Updating answer to finalize with this part.